# How to fold table columns into rows on mobile devices?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm developing a website featuring a restaurant's menu. Each item is available in different sizes, each at a different price. This is displayed on medium and large devices using a table, with a column for each price:

[image: Menu in columns]

On mobile devices, the screen is too narrow to properly display up to 4 different sizes per product.

So I would like to fold columns into rows, having each row starting with the column name:

[image]

Is there anything like this possible using a responsive design? I'm trying to avoid maintaining two different HTML versions of the content, one visible only on mobile, and one visible only on larger screens.

I'm using Foundation 5, so I'm ideally looking for a solution using this grid system, but I'm open to any solution really.

Comment: Both _Small_ , and _Large_ repeat with every product. So I guess you'll have to use foundation's **visibility** classes.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution involves making table cells `display: block` on mobile devices, and adding a `data-*` attribute to each cell, matching the column name.

This data attribute is injected in the cell's `::before` pseudo-element with `content: attr()`.

Example:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Pasta</th>
            <th>Small</th>
            <th>Regular</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Spaghetti Bolognese</td>
            <td data-th="Small">£5.00</td>
            <td data-th="Regular">£7.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lasagna</td>
            <td data-th="Small">£5.00</td>
            <td data-th="Regular">£7.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    thead th:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }

    td, th {
        display: block;
    }

    td[data-th]:before  {
        content: attr(data-th);
    }
}
```

You'll need to add some extra `float` to make it pretty.

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/medrZo

Comment: To make the codepen example work you need to wrap all the HTML with <html> and <body> tags.

Answer (score -1):

CSS changes for the above results

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    }

    td,
    th {
    padding: 0.5em;
    }

    th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    }

    thead th {
    background-color: #999;
    color: white;
    }

    td > div {
    float: right;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 885px) {
thead th:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

thead th:first-child:after {
    content: "'s";
}

td, th {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}
td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}

td[data-th]:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-width: 10rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

}